# How do I write out a mixed geometry geodataframe to a geopackage?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a geodataframe of several thousand rows, mixed geometry (Point, LineString, Polygon).  I would like to write this out to a geopackage with different layers per geometry type.  Here's what I've got so far (in jupyter nb):

```
import geopandas as gpd
%matplotlib inline

geojson_file = "C:/Temp/data.geojson"

gdf = gpd.read_file(geojson_file)

gdf.head() # yields good results
gdf.plot() # draws all the various geometries where they should be

gpkg = "C:/Temp/converted.gpkg"
gdf.to_file(gpkg, driver="GPKG")
```

Then when I load the layers...

```
import fiona
for ln in fiona.listlayers(gpkg):
    with fiona.open(gpkg, layer=ln) as dataset:
        print(ln, len(dataset))
```

it only gives me

```
converted 10000
```

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**: I'm on Windows 10, Python 3.8 (anaconda), and GeoPandas 0.8.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each layer of GeoPackage can contain a single geometry type not mixed. You have to save different geom types to separate layers.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
%matplotlib inline

geojson_file = "C:/Temp/data.geojson"

gdf = gpd.read_file(geojson_file)

gdf.head() # yields good results
gdf.plot() # draws all the various geometries where they should be

gpkg = "C:/Temp/converted.gpkg"

for geomtype in gdf.geom_type.unique():
   gdf[gdf.geom_type == geomtype].to_file(gpkg, driver="GPKG", layer=geomtype)
```

Comment: Gorgeous!  I knew layers could only contain one geometric type, but I wasn't sure if geopandas (fiona) would break them out automatically into their primitives.  I'll set myself a task next week to pull the documentation and submit a generic version of your answer for inclusion.

Comment: I was maybe wrong. GPKG can have multiple geoms and for points and polygons IO with geopandas works, so there may be something else happening.

Answer (score 0):

I recently figured out a way to create multiple layers in a geopackage file output.

First you need to get a list of all the geometries you want to write out.

```
buffer_geometries = ['geom1', 'geom2']
```

Next, use a similar for loop to the one mentioned by martinfleis.

```
for buffer_geometry in buffer_geometries:
   pes_gdf[buffer_geometry].to_file(output_path, driver="GPKG", layer=buffer_geometry)
```

This worked for me. But I would like to improve it by additionally including other columns in the export, still thinking about the best way to do that.

Comment: If you want to talk about your problem, post it as a question. Otherwise keep it as answer by removing the last lines. Kindly take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).