# Coordinates of features loaded correctly but export as '0,0' using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm exporting PostGIS tables as GeoPackages using GeoPandas, and something strange is happening specifically with non-point type geometries. The GeoDataFrames look fine after the `gpd.read_postgis()` function and correctly return area and bounding boxes, but they don't plot correctly and once they are exported, the geometry attribute has nothing but `0,0` coordinates.

I get the same error when I load the geometries in as a list - polygons are all exported with nodes at `0,0` while the point features are fine.

Code:

```
# Sample WKTs
wktlist = [
"MULTIPOLYGON (((505146.317461285 6472980.79042639, 505146.296872251 6472980.84016185, 505146.300938278 6472980.83808368, 505146.317461285 6472980.79042639)), ((505146.300938278 6472980.83808368, 505146.276043612 6472980.90988733, 505146.284241592 6472981.05993231, 505146.412978728 6472981.16143986, 505146.531241644 6472981.30280765, 505146.642025393 6472981.23416039, 505146.651660998 6472981.26426523, 505146.833488049 6472981.10650147, 505146.845879104 6472980.90672104, 505146.737371596 6472980.78546307, 505146.669083741 6472980.64469429, 505146.487975502 6472980.74248797, 505146.300938278 6472980.83808368)))"
,"POLYGON ((505109.124653986 6472991.30073289, 505108.52870163 6472993.48281169, 505109.971748607 6472994.01992362, 505111.084480991 6472994.59306213, 505112.705760951 6472995.27226066, 505113.277256696 6472996.79857076, 505113.822224707 6472999.70407267, 505114.999120245 6472999.92810459, 505115.328476423 6472999.97203811, 505115.617390309 6472998.38606592, 505115.916538809 6472996.78022351, 505116.666301451 6472995.10980711, 505117.664604606 6472995.22173746, 505120.265515538 6472995.90268161, 505120.419805019 6472996.374364, 505120.263102533 6472997.77198841, 505119.738261839 6472999.02524996, 505120.844405105 6473000.14811413, 505122.602089559 6473000.28913948, 505123.823945435 6472999.26415434, 505124.131291915 6472997.80835689, 505123.864798019 6472995.85585533, 505123.782407409 6472993.5556848, 505124.205620747 6472992.44115537, 505121.944300599 6472991.78427453, 505119.439386304 6472991.4343638, 505116.980202569 6472990.60517171, 505116.536280401 6472991.77943159, 505115.360582882 6472991.45544957, 505112.904514017 6472990.36638719, 505111.360438696 6472989.91803234, 505110.657536269 6472991.84891804, 505109.699812179 6472991.68749186, 505109.851893795 6472991.50937868, 505109.124653986 6472991.30073289))"
,"POLYGON ((505109.224244697 6472991.33191594, 505108.345556759 6472993.75052056, 505109.680575443 6472994.12639448, 505111.208785436 6472995.0643851, 505112.417138097 6472997.66794859, 505113.453778517 6473000.41940062, 505115.385331633 6473000.23262723, 505116.66506951 6472998.54857034, 505118.121311144 6472990.478899, 505116.226691589 6472990.08632115, 505115.704486558 6472991.11969245, 505111.225180818 6472989.52654966, 505110.379472975 6472991.69563841, 505109.860930389 6472991.58945858, 505109.871644214 6472991.52960831, 505109.224244697 6472991.33191594))"
,"POLYGON ((505115.585248832 6472998.56561672, 505115.578882345 6473000.76475889, 505119.84322669 6473000.27606405, 505122.666612118 6472999.91004784, 505123.196005302 6472998.27697584, 505122.912208455 6472996.93405019, 505120.927582363 6472995.71068833, 505119.184804817 6472995.15998731, 505117.487569649 6472994.97970074, 505115.707310954 6472995.88803182, 505115.585248832 6472998.56561672))",
'POINT(505109.473401175 6472991.39488107)'
]

# Dependencies to load list into a GDF
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

# Create GDF and declare CRS
df = pd.DataFrame(wktlist,columns=['geometry'])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads),crs=3006)

# Check GDF validity. Geometry column looks fine, area calculations and bounding boxes look correct, but the plot and exports show issues with the polygon features
gdf.head()

geometry
0   MULTIPOLYGON (((505146.317 6472980.790, 505146...
1   POLYGON ((505109.125 6472991.301, 505108.529 6...
2   POLYGON ((505109.224 6472991.332, 505108.346 6...
3   POLYGON ((505115.585 6472998.566, 505115.579 6...
4   POINT (505109.473 6472991.395)

print(gdf.area)
0     0.241603
1    86.882849
2    61.075354
3    34.772683
4     0.000000

print(gdf.bounds)
            minx          miny           maxx          maxy
0  505146.276044  6.472981e+06  505146.845879  6.472981e+06
1  505108.528702  6.472990e+06  505124.205621  6.473000e+06
2  505108.345557  6.472990e+06  505118.121311  6.473000e+06
3  505115.578882  6.472995e+06  505123.196005  6.473001e+06
4  505109.473401  6.472991e+06  505109.473401  6.472991e+06

# Plot shows the point and is stretched to include the 0,0 coordinate
gdf.plot()
```

[image]

```
# A GeoJSON export of the final two features shows the polygon coming out without correct coordinates, and the point coming out correctly. Other export formats show the same pattern.
geojson = gdf.tail(2).to_json()
print(geojson)

{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "3", "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]]}}, {"id": "4", "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [505109.473401175, 6472991.39488107]}}]}
```

Comment: Update your packages, works for me with numpy '1.21.5', geoopandas '0.10.2', shapely '1.8.0', matplotlib '3.5.1'. Note you still won't be able to export as-is to geopackage which doesn't support layers with mixed geometry types - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/375637/2856

Comment: Thanks @user2856, will update the environment and check again! BTW you can export a mixed-type GeoPackage layer, but you might have issues depending on where you're loading it (e.g. in ESRI products). QGIS just parses it out into different types without requiring the different spatial types to be stored in separate tables.